# Reading wave files for mono conversion (Minix 3)

Tags: c, wav, minix

I'm about to start working on a project for Minix 3 (in C).

My idea is to create some kind of a music player. I want to be able to read files (WAV) and then convert them to a stream of frequencies send to the Timer 2.
Since, has far as I know, there is no easy way to read real music files, I thought of approaching the real frequencies in a block, to a simple mono curve sent to the timer 2. 
Ok, issues:

1. I read and learned, how to read wav headers, but, I can't find anywhere what's the meaning of the data in the data chunk. How should I interpret it?
2. My initial idea was to make a real music player, but, in my classes we didn't learned how to work with the sound board in Minix 3. Is there some tutorial, anything where I can learn it?
3. As far as I could realize, C as already a library to manage sound (BASS). Can and How I install it in Minix 3?
4. Finally, Is it a way to make all this simpler?

Comment: http://www.raspberryginger.com/jbailey/minix/html/playwave_8c-source.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The thing is that I need to implemented my own solution. And I cannot really understand that.

Answer (score 0):

A WAV files is not a "stream of frequencies". It contains a series of samples formatted according to the information written in the header.

In best of worlds you just set up your sound card to handle the data format specified in the header, then you just have to keep providing the raw data in the "DATA" chunks to your sound cards data buffers.

How this is done in Minix 3 is out of bounds for this answer (I just don't know how Minix handles sound at all) but I'm sure it will be to great help for understanding the basics of digital audio.